# How to make a POJO returns the modified value in setter whenever Autowired in any other Service?

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans, autowired, event-listener

So I was having a requirement where I need to call a service( you can call it a class with @Service ) which has autowired a POJO ( which has getters/setters). Now if that POJO is being modified using setters , any other service autowiring this POJO should always get me the modified attribute.

```
@Service
class A {

@Autowired
private Hello hello;

public void initHello(){
hello.setName();
}

}

@Component
class Hello {
private String name;

//getters and setters

}

//Any other service
@Service
class B{

@Autowired
private Hello hello;

public String getName(){
return hello.getName(); //should return the same name being set in class A
}
```

**And initHello() is called on @EventListener .**

Need to implement this feature. Can someone help me achieve this functionality as googling about it has no leads.

Comment: _...should return the same name being set in class A_. Well, not necessarily, you don't know for sure service `A` will be loaded (and the method `initHello` executed) first and then Service `B` loaded (and method `getName` executed) after `A`

Comment: `Hello` just needs to be a Spring managed bean with singleton (default) scope so all classes share the same injected instance.  Concurrent access would not be thread safe though - there will need to be some code to guard the read/write.

Comment: How about if I changed the value of name on runtime. Will it be reflected in all the classes autowiring Hello.